# Does a reference field need to be volatile if I modify it during a lock?

Tags: c#, multithreading, reference, locking, volatile

Consider the following code, which takes place in a background thread ("thread B"):

```
List<T> invocationQueueCopy;
lock (invocationQueue)
{
    invocationQueueCopy = invocationQueue;
    invocationQueue = new List<T>();
}
```

In another thread ("thread A") I simply lock "invocationQueue" before adding to it:

```
lock (invocationQueue)
{
    invocationQueue.Add(args);
}
```

I have read that reference assignment is atomic, but could it ever occur that "thread A" will end up writing to the old list (the one replaced in "thread B") after receiving the lock? I have read other answers that imply it could, if the value of the reference were stored in a register on "thread A" then it would not know that "thread B" had modified the value in the class. If this is so, would declaring "invocationQueue" volatile prevent this?

Notes:

- I know I could clone then clear the list.
- I
  know I could have a separate lock
  object for the list.

But I'd rather not do either of these things unless it is required.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Just to clarify from Adam's comments: invocationQueue is a private field which is created internally to this class and never exposed to the outside world so nothing could lock on it except these two methods.

Comment: the code is quite bad, you need a separate (non-modifiable, read-only) object to serve as monitor and `lock()` on it, not the queue itself.

Comment: +1 to bestsss, but it also looks like you should be using a real queue such as Queue<T> rather than trying to roll your own. you could also use ConcurrentQueue<T> but I usually prefer to do my own explicit thread synchronization to keep it to a minimum

Comment: @best, that is slightly exaggerated. As long as `invocationQueue` is private there is no practical difference. Just a theoretical argument that a future version of `List<>` could start doing `lock(this)`. Very unlikely.

Comment: @Henk, what do you mean? you can't guard an object reference via the reference itself, private or not. it's one of the common mistakes to put the lock into the object it guards.

Comment: @Henk: agreed that the initial comment is slightly exaggerated. However, @OP - I think it's usually worth having explicit lock objects, e.g. at some point even a private List<T> may be assigned from an argument constructor and then who knows which code may have a reference to it? Also with explicit lock objects it's easier to express an intended locking context by the name of the variable which may be useful in some cases.

Comment: @best: Yes you can. As long as you don't change it like the OP does. The TreadA code is OK, ThreadB is not. But you are right that a separate object is the 'best practice'.

Comment: @Adam: no contest there. But you can easily oversee access to a private object (your separate lockObject could also be assigned from anywhere. You just don't do that.)

Comment: @Henk,i guess there is a misunderstand, then. I mean the reference into the 'class' (not the content pointed by that reference), i.e. if the reference `invocationQueue` doesn't change, there is no need to guard it. Normally I'd write the code w/ CAS and no locking but that's irrelevant.

Comment: @Adam Can you expand on this comment, or provide a link please? "at some point even a private List<T> may be assigned from an argument constructor and then who knows which code may have a reference to it?"

Comment: @Adam In this scenario, what practical advantage does Queue have over List?

Comment: @best: look at the ThreadA code. The assignment in ThreadB does not have to be locked (a reference is atomic), just prevented from being cached.

Comment: @OP: let's say an object foo is passed as a constructor argument and assigned to a local field, and there is a public method on your type which locks on foo. Some consuming code locks on foo, calls your public method and hey presto, deadlock! If you use a private readonly field which is assigned inline, e.g. `private readonly object fooLock = new object();` then it has no use apart from locking and will never be assigned otherwise. You can safely lock on it only having to worry about other locks taken within your type.

Comment: @OP: I made the Queue<T> recommendation because it looks like, essentially, you are trying to roll your own queue. The types are named as queues and it looks like the intention is to let stuff queue up, then take it off the queue by taking a copy of the list, and creating a new one for new items to be queued. This is already done for you in the pre-built queue types.

Comment: @Adam I have updated the question to clarify that invocationQueue is entirely private to this class, I think this makes your concern about deadlocking moot?

Comment: @Adam It seems to me Queue is useful when you want to remove single objects. My goal here is to clear the queue entirely during the lock, to minimise the amount of time spent locking. So to all intents + purposes I think List and Queue are identical here.

Comment: @OP: yes, given that the field is private and that the object cannot be accessed by consumers will ensure the type works _in it's current form_. However, it seems to me that invocation list is part of the implementation of the _semantics_ of the type which are not necessarily related to thread safety. One could argue that thread safety is also part of the type semantics but I think it's implementation should be separate. I grant that this is rather defensive coding, but I still believe it's worth doing as this will make future changes to the type much less risky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** Your solution will work. Lock creates a [full fence](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Full_fences) so any caching is prevented, basically meaning you'll always get the most recent value for the list reference. The only thing, as suggested in the comments is the fact that you should do the locking on a neutral object, not the list itself.

The following is wrong!! But I let it here anyway to show how fu*** hard threading might be... the fact is the following reasoning is defeated by the fact that lock creates a full fence.

> Yeah, it can happen so don't do it
>   that way.
>
> It won't get better even if you did
>   the lock into a readonly whatever
>   object.
>
> See what might happen (although most
>   of the time it WON'T happen).
>
> ThreadA and ThreadB are executing on
>   different processors, each one with
>   its own cache memory which holds the
>   reference to incovationQueue.
>
> - ThreadB locks invocationQueue, the lock is done to a reference which is
>     taken for the cache of processor1, not
>     to a variable name.
> - ThreadB copies the invocationQueue.
> - ThreadA locks invocationQueue, the lock is done to a reference which is
>     taken for the cache on processor2 and
>     which, in this moment is the same as
>     the one in processor1, and starts
>     waiting.
> - ThreadB creates a new List and assigns it to the invocationQueue, the
>     cache in the processor1 is updated but
>     since the variable is NOT volatile
>     that's all that happens.
> - ThreadA enters the lock and gets the reference from his cache, which points
>     to the old reference, therefore you
>     end up adding the variable to the old
>     list.
>
> So you need to make the list volatile
>   AND use the lock if you're going to be
>   playing with the reference itself.

Comment: Yes, +1 for needing to do both things the OP wanted to avoid. And it still looks flaky, queued items are being discarded. They better not be important.

Comment: @Jorge I want to make sure I understand your answer before I mark it. Are you saying my code would be fine (and not lose any items) as long as I replaced _lock (invocationQueue)_ with _lock (specialLockObject)_ ?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I'm saying :) The thing is the lock will establish a full memory barrier, so threadA is guaranteed to get the most actual value of the invocationQueue anyway.